# Why I am getting only one item out of this Observable?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a cold observable with static number of items, I needed some time delay between each item, I have combined it with another IObservable I got through `Observable.Timer`. I am using `Zip` .

```
var ob1 = Observable.Range(1, 100);
var ob2 = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

var myObservable = Observable.Zip(ob1, ob2, (a, b) => b);

myObservable.Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("Item encountered"));

///Allow enough time for Timer observable to give back multiple ticks
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

But output only prints "Item encountered" once. What am I missing ?

Comment: What sort of application are you running this from?

Comment: You put this code in Console Application. You put it *anywhere* the behavior is same.

Comment: Are you blocking the console application from exiting until the observable completes?

Comment: I guess that is what Thread.Sleep(3000) does. Should we not get at least 3 elements because Sleep is blocking for 3 seconds ?

Answer (score 4):

To confirm the commentary, `Observable.Interval` is the way to go for just a single argument - and thus it has always been!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.  Observable.Timer takes two arguments for my scenario, first one is due time for *first* item and second due time is for all subsequent items. And if only one `TimeSpan` argument is supplied, it would yield only one item.

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

Comment: I don't think that the behaviour changed in the way you think. `Interval` does what you want, `Timer(Timspan)` always only returned one result.

Comment: I used to accomplish what I did here with just one TimeSpan argument.

Comment: You sure about what you said Timer(TimeSpan) behavior ? I will remove my remark. That was what I remember.

Comment: Lets wait for one more guy confirming this then I'll remove my remarks. I thought the behavior used to be different. I will refer to the older versions of the source.

Comment: @MatthewFinlay I would have to go with you here. I could not find any older version of that source (thanks to the blankety blank CodePlex source viewer). https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable.Time.cs

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.reactive.observable_methods%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is some documentation from 2 years ago.

Comment: That windows phone Rx. And it does not clarify how many items it produces. The only supporting part is 'a value'.

Comment: It is the windows phone version, which makes it even older (as it wasn't updated as rapidly, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/10/28/rx-for-windows-phone-7.aspx). Compare the documentation `Timer` "produces a value after the dueTime has elapsed" vs `Interval` "produces a value after each period"